# Make image visible on button click in XAML

Tags: xaml

I am making my first universal windows app. I am using C++ and XAML. I want an image to be displayed on the screen when a button click event occurs. How can I do this?

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Margin="444,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="393" Source="Assets/b.png"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="564,617,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="release"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: In C# I can do that by set image Visibility to Collapsed or Opacity = 0. I think it similar in C++

Comment: you want to achieve through code or XAML?

Comment: @HelloWindowsPhone Thanks it worked